# Actionscript3, why does this happen?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm get the delta time for each frame, and this is how i do it..

```
private var currFrame:Number,lastFrame:Number,delta:Number,playerX:Number = 10;
public function step(e:Event):void 
    {   
        trace(playerX);
        currFrame = getTimer();
        delta = (currFrame - lastFrame) / 1000;
        lastFrame = currFrame;

        playerX += (delta);
    }
```

And the result is 'NaN' on every frame. But this works

```
     private var currFrame:Number,lastFrame:Number=0,delta:Number,playerX:Number = 10;
     public function step(e:Event):void 
    {   
        trace(playerX);
        currFrame = getTimer();
        delta = (currFrame - lastFrame) / 1000;
        lastFrame = currFrame;

        playerX += (delta);
    }
```

the difference if you don't notice is "lastFrame:Number=0"

Any idea why, im moving from java to Actionscript3, so the more information the better :)

gettimer is this:   import flash.utils.Timer;

Comment: When you call the function, are you sending in the lastFrame value?

Comment: What does the `getTimer()` function call return? can you share the code for that function?

Comment: @DamienBlack, are you referring to the `step` function or the `getTimer` function? the `step` function doesn't require the `lastFrame` object to be passed to it. however, this is assuming that the `step` function and those privately declared variables are members of the same class

Comment: @SlyRaskal Oh, I'm sorry, I read it wrong. I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, `lastFrame:Number=0`, is setting the value of `lastFrame` to 0 when it is created. If the value of lastFrame isn't set to 0, then it's value is `undefined`. In AS2, `undefined` would get treated like 0. In AS3, `undefined` is treated like `NaN`.

Doing any calculation with `NaN` returns `NaN`. For example: `5 + NaN = NaN`.So the first time you run your function you are doing this:

```
delta = (currFrame - NaN) / 1000; //set delta to NaN
lastFrame = currFrame; // sets lastFrame to something besides NaN

playerX += (delta); //sets playerX to NaN
```

Now your `lastFrame` isn't `NaN`, it seems like things should be working, however, `playerX` is now `NaN`, so the line:

```
playerX += (delta); // will always be NaN now, even if delta is not NaN
```

Will keep playerX at `NaN` forever. Because `NaN + Anything` is still `NaN`. So `NaN += Anything` is always `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about "NaN + Anything is still NaN", I feel really stupid , I spent like 15 min saying to myself why is that happing, can you forgive be for my stupidity? But Thanks for the help :).